# How can I style my option/selector tags to be inline?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my page look more nice and I would like for my page to look like this
[image: Size on top with quantity selector on bottom]

But this is what it looks like now
https://codepen.io/amoney73/pen/KKmWPro

```
<div class="clearfix elOrderProductOptinLabel">
<div class="pull-left qty-head"><b>Qty</b></div><div class="productRight pull-left elOrderProductOptinItem">Item</div>
<div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinLabelPrice">Price</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix elOrderProductOptinProducts" data-cf-product-template="true">
<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
<input type="radio" id="pid-3613808-0" name="purchase[product_id]" value="3613808" data-product-label="S- Self Love Summer Shirt" data-product-payment-type="onetime" data-product-amount="22.0" data-product-currency-code="USD" data-business-name="" data-product-name="S- Self Love Summer Shirt" class="hide"><select id="3613808_qty" name="3613808_qty" class="qty_select box" data-product-id="3613808"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select>
<div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$22</div>
<label class="productSize productLeft" for="pid-3613808-0" data-cf-product-name="true">S</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix elOrderProductOptinProducts" data-cf-product-template="true">
<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
<input type="radio" id="pid-3611228-0" name="purchase[product_id]" value="3611228" data-product-label="M- Self Love Summer Shirt" data-product-payment-type="onetime" data-product-amount="22.0" data-product-currency-code="USD" data-business-name="" data-product-name="M- Self Love Summer Shirt" class="hide"><select id="3611228_qty" name="3611228_qty" class="qty_select box" data-product-id="3611228"><option value="0">M</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select>
<div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$22</div>
<label class="productSize productLeft" for="pid-3611228-0" data-cf-product-name="true">M</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix elOrderProductOptinProducts" data-cf-product-template="true">
<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
<input type="radio" id="pid-3611229-0" name="purchase[product_id]" value="3611229" data-product-label="L- Self Love Summer Shirt" data-product-payment-type="onetime" data-product-amount="22.0" data-product-currency-code="USD" data-business-name="" data-product-name="L- Self Love Summer Shirt" class="hide"><select id="3611229_qty" name="3611229_qty" class="qty_select box" data-product-id="3611229"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select>
<div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$22</div>
<label class="productSize productLeft" for="pid-3611229-0" data-cf-product-name="true">L</label>
</div>
</div>


<div class="clearfix elOrderProductOptinProducts" data-cf-product-template="true">
<div class="pull-left elOrderProductOptinProductName">
<input type="radio" id="pid-3611231-0" name="purchase[product_id]" value="3611231" data-product-label="XL- Self Love Summer Shirt" data-product-payment-type="onetime" data-product-amount="22.0" data-product-currency-code="USD" data-business-name="" data-product-name="XL- Self Love Summer Shirt" class="hide">
<select id="3611231_qty" name="3611231_qty" class="qty_select box" data-product-id="3611231"><option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select>
  <div class="pull-right elOrderProductOptinPrice" data-cf-product-price="true" taxamo-currency="USD">$22</div>
<label class="productSize productLeft" for="pid-3611229-0" data-cf-product-name="true">XL</label>

</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try this structure - <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between"><div style="display: flex"><div><label style="display: block">S</label><select><option>1</option>...</div>.....</div><label>$22</label></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example, Flexbox is useful.

```
<div style="background-color: blue; color: white; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; padding: 1rem;">
  <div style="display: flex;">
     <div>
       <label style="display: block;">S</label>
       <select>
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div>
       <label style="display: block;">M</label>
       <select>
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div>
       <label style="display: block;">L</label>
       <select>
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
       </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top: 1.5rem;">$ 22</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. One last thing. How do you center it?

Comment: justify-content: center;